# Managing user input widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, tkinter-layout

apologies in advance for the broadness of this question:

I am building a user interface in python/tkinter.  It works fine atm but I'm running into some scaling issues and I wonder whether I should shift gears before I get any deeper on it.

The interface currently consists of a grid containing frames, labels and buttons, all of which update with user input.  I'm currently up to around 25 buttons.  I create them during the **init** and immediately use pack_forget to stow them away until they're needed.  I then use custom methods to pack() and pack_forget() to get me back to the button arrangement I need depending on the state of the environment.  Generally I'm triggering those loadout transitions with button clicks (so the user clicking a button will often change which buttons are on the 'control panel').  Here is an example:

```
def member_buttons(self):  # updates control panel if current instance is a member object
        if self.selected_item in self.member_list:
            self.add_button.pack_forget()
            self.drain_button.pack_forget()
            self.boost_button.pack_forget()
            self.remove_button.pack(side='left', fill='y')
            self.drain_button.pack(side='left', fill='y')
            self.boost_button.pack(side='left', fill='y')
```

(all this is really doing is swapping in remove_button for add_button... drain_button and boost_button are only being re-packed so it stays in the same order.  I'm attaching it here so it's clear what I mean when I talk about loadout methods (since I don't know what else to call them yet). i'm using similar mechanics for managing my key binds).

I just started building these loadouts.  Everything works fine but it's already starting to feel a little crazy (I anticipate needing dozens of them).  Here are my questions:

1. is there a better technique for this? For instance would I be better off storing loadouts onto distinct frames and then swapping between those in the appropriate grid locations?  Or is there a better overall technique for dealing with this within tkinter?
2. what would you call this sort of exercise (button management, dynamic GUI, loadout manager)? Can anyone point me to a good essay on the subject?
3. finally (and most specifically) is there a good way to simulate a pop-up window within tkinter - for instance if I want to prompt a tk.Entry() box that 'shuts down' all the hotkeys until it's satisfactorily completed?  I know I could do this by disabling all the hotkeys and wrapping the input field, but is that the right way to do it?  Seems like something that would come up frequently in GUIs.

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems too broad and is asking too many things. It needs more focus, and should have a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you.

The member_buttons() method isn't enough for an MRE?  I don't really have a problem to solve, I'm just worried that the process I'm using is a bad one and was looking for feedback/alternatives/nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I sorted this out.  To answer my own questions:

1. swapping between labels (via pack/pack_forget) is definitely an option, but I found it easier to manage the buttons and key binds directly.  I set up little button-manager methods (similar to the one provided above) and used pack_forget and unbind (you can simply do "for key in root.bind(): root.unbind(key)" to start from scratch with key binds).  I'm currently up to 4 manager methods and will probably end up with around 20 of them, but they're reliable and fairly efficient (even if they fill a lot of lines in my gui module).
2. I still don't know what this process is called (GUI management?).  It may simply be the case that tkinter was the wrong tool for what I'm trying to achieve, but at this point I'm pot-committed.
3. I wound up ditching the faux-pop-up and using one of my button-manager methods to temporarily empty out the user-input label / control panel.  Basically re-purposing an existing frame/label rather than triggering an inside-the-root popup (like I'd intended).